# How to pass command line argument for Spring's @PropertySource annotation?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, maven

**Description:**

As a test developer, I would like to select a specific property file before executing a test.

**Question :**

How do I call the desired property in the command line?

I am using `mvn` to build my project.

**Idea :**

I was thinking of something like :

`~mvn clean verify -Dproperty.source.project1=QA1 -Dproperty.source.project2=QA2`

It would be nice to handle multiple property select in the command line ( like the line above ) since this project will have multiple `"propertycontrollers"`

Code :

```
package com.core.propertycontroller;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.PropertySource;
import org.springframework.context.support.PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer;

@Configuration
@PropertySource("classpath:application-${env}.properties")
//This project will have Project2PropertyLoader.class, and so on and so forth.
public class Project1PropertyLoader {

    public Project1PropertyLoader() { super();}

    @Bean
    public static PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer propertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer() {
        return new PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer();
    }
}
```

Im using the `@ContextConfiguration` to load this class.

```
package com.testrunners;

import com.core.propertycontroller.Project1PropertyLoader;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.core.env.Environment;
import org.springframework.test.context.ContextConfiguration;
import org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner;
import org.springframework.test.context.support.AnnotationConfigContextLoader;

@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = { Project1PropertyLoader.class } , loader = AnnotationConfigContextLoader.class)
public class EnvironmentTest {

    @Autowired
    private Environment environment;

    @Value("${sample.url}")
    private String url;

    @Test
    public void printUrl() {
        System.out.println("Project1PropertyLoader Url via @Value " + url);
        System.out.println("Project1PropertyLoader Url via Environment " + environment.getProperty("sample.url"));
    }
}
```

application-QA1.properties

`sample.url = https://hello.com`

application-QA2.properties

`sample.url = https://world.com`

***UPDATE:***
Alternative solutions are also welcome. I am all ears.
Thank you

Comment: The compiler evaluates annotation metadata for RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME annotations at compile time and hence can't be changed dynamically at runtime. What you can do is have "token' templates and save files as .template and based on your mvn command, generate a java file with correct annotation's attribute value and then compile it

Comment: You can use spring profiling and in your SpringBootTest class you can put the annotation "@ActiveProfiles" by specifying the desired environment, for example dev, qa or test.

Answer (score 0):

Since you named your files `application-${env}.properties`, you should just use the built-in "profile" feature of Spring Boot.

See [Spring Boot Reference Documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.2.1.RELEASE/reference/html/index.html), section [Spring Boot Feature](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.2.1.RELEASE/reference/html/spring-boot-features.html#boot-features), chapter [2. Externalized Configuration](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.2.1.RELEASE/reference/html/spring-boot-features.html#boot-features-external-config), which lists:

> 12. [Profile-specific application properties](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.2.1.RELEASE/reference/html/spring-boot-features.html#boot-features-external-config-profile-specific-properties) outside of your packaged jar (`application-{profile}.properties` and YAML variants).
> 13. [Profile-specific application properties](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.2.1.RELEASE/reference/html/spring-boot-features.html#boot-features-external-config-profile-specific-properties) packaged inside your jar (`application-{profile}.properties` and YAML variants)

And chapter [3. Profiles](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.2.1.RELEASE/reference/html/spring-boot-features.html#boot-features-profiles), which says *(paraphrased)*:

> You can specify the profile on the command line by using the following switch:
>
> `--spring.profiles.active=QA1`

Read the documentation of the two chapters linked above to learn more about this powerful feature.

Comment: Profiles rely on the `application.properties` file, this would assume you only have `1` Project `1` property class loader. No? Or can this work even with multiple simultaneous environments being called?

Comment: @GheenoSanPascualIII No, profiles are entirely independent of properties. They are related, in that Spring Boot will attempt to load profile-specific property files, using the shown naming convention. But profiles can also be used e.g. to control whether Spring Beans are available or not, by using the [`@Profile`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/Profile.html) annotation. --- Both properties and profiles are managed by the Spring `ApplicationContext`, so are not restricted to `1` Project `1` property class loader.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively you can set default values for you properties as below.

```
@Value("${some.key:stackoverflow.com}")
private String url;
```

in above example stackoverflow.com will be effective url is nothing is provided.